# How to untag all with Javascript?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I'm struggling with something that should be fairly easy I think. I have a few docs that are already tagged, but these should be redone. I have all scripts up and running to renew tags, so that's fine, but up till now I'm removing all tags by selecting them in the structure pane and selecting the untag command before running my scripts.

Obviously I want to do this with script, I found that I need to use associatedXMLElements.untag(); but I can't make it work...

Can someone help me with the script ? I simply want to remove every tag, so the document is again as blank as when it was originally made (only root element)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The everyItem() collection method can often be used equivalent to a loop.
Therefor to iterate all (open) documents, keep the root element but untag everything below, just do the following:

```
app.documents.everyItem().xmlElements.item(0).xmlElements.everyItem().untag();
```